# Mootools Fx.Slide: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, mootools, slide

I want to make one div to slideOut, but I get an error..

Code

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.5/mootools-yui-compressed.js"></script>

window.addEvent('domready', function() {

  var div = new Fx.Slide('divID');
  div.slideOut();
});
```

The error is just below `var div`

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the `Fx.Slide` helper is not part of Mootools Core, it is part of the `More` package. The CDN file you are loading is only the Core. You will need to find another CDN that  hosts More, or serve it from your own server.

It looks like Google doesn't host More at the moment: http://code.google.com/p/google-ajax-apis/issues/detail?id=135

For more info, as it says right at the top of the main download page: http://mootools.net/download

```
From this page you can download the full MooTools Core. If you need more
functionality, head over to the More Builder.
```

So go here: http://mootools.net/more/ and check off any `More` features you want. Check off `Fx.Slide` and click download at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I download this: http://mootools.net/nightly/build/mootools-more.js and now the error is gone. Thanks :)

Comment: @fufu That's the nightly build, the most up-to-date Mootools, so it could contain bugs. I've updated my answer to include download instructions for you for stable.